# Node Js Cli with mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I created a `Commander.js` command which creates an account but I don't get any feedback of errors or even success

here is the file

```
 #!/usr/bin/env node

const program = require('commander');
const userModel = require('../mongo/userModel');
const bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs');

program
  .version('0.0.1')
  .description('Contact management system');

program
  .command('createadminaccount <name> <username> <email> <password>')
  .alias('c')
  .description('Add a admin account')
  .action((name, username, email,password) => {

    userModel.findOne({email: email}, function (err, existingUser) {
      if (err) return console.log("Error");
      if (existingUser) {
        return console.log('Email is already registered');
      }

      let newUser = new userModel({
        name: req.body.name,
        username: req.body.username,
        email:req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        staffMember: true,
        verified: true
      })

      bcryptjs.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
        bcryptjs.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) return console.log("Error");
          newUser.password = hash;
          newUser.save();

          console.log('Registered Successfully')
        })
      })
    })
  });

program.parse(process.argv);
```

and here is the userModel file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  verified: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  staffMember: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
})

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I don't get any messages nor do the code creates an account in the database, even though I use the same method to create an account in API method, it's just that the code does not continue for example if I deleted `bcryptjs` import I will not get any errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you don't call the command name in the bash file `.command('createadminaccount ...')`, but in the name  of `package.json` like this

```
  "name": "createadminaccount",
```

then you need to define the name of the file in `bin` where you want it to be called (I assumed its called admincommander.js and its in the same folder of the `package.json` file) and also define prefer global to be true , also in the `package.json`

```
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "bin": "./admincommander.js"
```

After this run `npm link` to link the files (you can also later run `npm unlink` to unlink files)

then finally run `createadminaccount` and the magic will happen

I hope I have helped :)

Comment: I know about this if I added `console.log(name, username, email, password);` I would get the parameters I inserted, which means I'm reaching the code but the `userModel` function is not working....

Comment: can you please share your UserModal file content in your answer ?? because I replicated it exactly as you wrote the commander file and it worked perfectly...

Comment: I added the userModel

Comment: is this is the two only files ?? how do you connect to the database ?? where is `mongoose.connect()` ??

Comment: Oh now I get it I needed to add `mongo.connect()` I thought that mongo is already connected since I'm already running the backend server, thank you

Comment: One last thing when I register a new account and get `Registered Successfully` message I can't input new commands unless I press ctrl and c, I don't want that how can I do it?

Comment: i don't understand ?? can you explain more ?

Comment: When I execute the command and get `log` I can't input commands anymore unless I press ctrl and c, then I can type a new command

Comment: I think you should use `process.exit()` after the success happens, like after `newUser.save()`....check this example https://github.com/tj/commander.js/blob/master/examples/env